# How to do some thing to all class on js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

every body.

I try to make function as each function on `jquery` i make this code

```
var $ = function (e){
    var d = document
    if(e){
        if ("#" == e.substring(0, 1)) {
            return d.querySelectorAll(e);
        } else if ("." == e.substring(0, 1)) {
            return d.querySelectorAll(e);
        } else if ("." != e.substring(0, 1) && "#" != e.substring(0, 1)){
            return d.querySelectorAll(e)
        }
    }
}
```

i want it if i write `$(".example").style.background = "red";`

Comment: Are you saying you want to write your own implementation of jquery?

Comment: Also, you can use `e.startsWith('.')` in place of `e.substring(0, 1) == '.'`

Comment: yes want to write your own implementation of jquery  + thanks

Comment: what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want create each function, this code is work

```
function each(a,b) {
  var c = document.querySelectorAll(a);
  for(var i = c.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    return b.call(i, c[i]);
  }
}

//use

each(".class", function(e) {
  e.style.background = "red";
});
```

You need selector engine like sizzle if you want write `$(".class").style.background = "red";`

Comment: Thank :D you i make it by
` function each(a,b) {
  var c = document.querySelectorAll(a);
  for(var i=0, len = c.length; i < len; i++) {
    b.call(i, c[i]);
  }
}

//use

each(".hh", function(e) {
  e.style.background = "red";
}); `